# Move to svn changed new lines

Tags: svn, cvs, newline

We just migrated our cvs repo to collabnet svn and now all files it seems have \n instead of \r\n

Is there a way to change this? I am afraid this may introduce subtle bugs into our application.

We use ankhsvn Client in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe cvs might have been saving all the files with `\n` and our visual studio cvs plugin  was changing to `\r\n` so when I did the conversion I should have used the `--default-eol=CRLF` option.

It seems files we convert to `\r\n` and commit stay with `\r\n` so that is great. I might just have to checkout, change everything and re-commit.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `eol-style` for sources in subversion:

```
svn propset svn:eol-style native <path-to-source-file>
```

There are other options apart from `native`. From [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html):

- native

  > This causes the file to contain the EOL markers that are native to the
  >   operating system on which Subversion was run. In other words, if a
  >   user on a Windows machine checks out a working copy that contains a
  >   file with an svn:eol-style property set to native, that file will
  >   contain CRLF EOL markers. A Unix user checking out a working copy
  >   which contains the same file will see LF EOL markers in his copy of
  >   the file. Note that Subversion will actually store the file in the
  >   repository using normalized LF EOL markers regardless of the operating
  >   system. This is basically transparent to the user, though.
- CRLF

  > This causes the file to contain CRLF sequences for EOL markers,
  >   regardless of the operating system in use.
- LF

  > This causes the file to contain LF characters for EOL markers,
  >   regardless of the operating system in use.
- CR

  > This causes the file to contain CR characters for EOL markers,
  >   regardless of the operating system in use. This line ending style is
  >   not very common. It was used on older Macintosh platforms (on which
  >   Subversion doesn't even run).

Answer (score 1):

Per-client globally you can in config file define some auto-properties (which will apply to all Working Copies), svn:eol-style is one of good candidates

[auto-props] section, see comments in default file for

```
# *.c = svn:eol-style=native
# *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
```